# How can i allow a-frame to preview images from cloudfront (without CORS policy)?

Tags: image, amazon-cloudfront, aframe

I'm trying to create a 360º panorama viewer with A-Frame framework
I have some CORS policy when i'm trying to get images fromn cloudfront

I read the documentation and do the stuff localy, with an image uploaded in my project.
Everything works fine.

After that, i'm trying to get my image dynamicly, downloaded on Cloudfront.
I have one error on my console.

`Access to image at 'https://d2l35xunnm47ff.cloudfront.net/...1553267992.jpg' from origin  has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

You can show th problem in action
https://codepen.io/petitlardon/pen/ewYpGo

```
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <img id="panorama" src="https://d2l35xunnm47ff.cloudfront.net/media/clients/5addae3a37e62a001bf297ef/3aabb43a-4b0d-4a02-9f0b-f023ceaaf3af-54086-0072-f-1553268090.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  </a-assets>
  <a-sky src="#panorama"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

[Images must be served with CORS headers](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/introduction/faq.html#why-does-my-asset-e-g-image-video-model-not-load). Check Cloudfrount documentation on how to configure your instance. If it's not a server you manage there's nothing you can do, the owner is not allowing cross domain requests.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when trying to stream videos using AWS S3 and CloudFront. I was able to resolve it with the following steps:

1. Setup CORS permissions on the S3 bucket where the videos are hosted following these recommendations: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html
2. Update `Behaviour` of the CloudFront distribution which originates from the above-mentioned bucket using the recommendations: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html#header-caching-web-cors
3. Make sure to clean the cache of the browser when you test the changes. The browser may cache old CORS policies. I've wasted hours before I came to that conclusion and finally got rid of the error.